# An ArrayList containing objects I have constructed is printing these as null

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I have a `Task` class and a `Dev` class. I am assigning tasks to devs, and am logging which tasks are assigned to each dev in an `ArrayList` contained within Dev. This is my method in `Task` that assigns the particular task to the particular dev, with the Task constructor below it:

```
public void setAssignedDev(Dev dev){
        this.assignedDev=dev;       
        dev.addToTasksAssigned(this);          
    }

 public Task(String newProject,String newDescription, float newEarliestStartTime,float newDuration,float newLatestFinishTime,boolean newIsTaskReferenced,ArrayList<Dev> newListDevs){
    project=newProject;
    description=newDescription;
    earliestStartTime=newEarliestStartTime;
    duration=newDuration;
    latestFinishTime=newLatestFinishTime;
    isTaskReferenced=newIsTaskReferenced;
    newListDevs=new ArrayList<Dev>(); 

};
```

The `setAssignedDev()` method triggers the `ArrayList<Task>` in `Dev` to log the task, and then the list is sorted:

```
public Dev(String newName){
    name=newName;
    tasksAssigned=new ArrayList<Task>();
}

public void addToTasksAssigned(Task task){              
    this.tasksAssigned.add(task);    
    //sort list by allotted start time
    Collections.sort(tasksAssigned, new Comparator<Task>(){            
        @Override
        public int compare(Task t1, Task t2){
          if(t2.getAllottedStartTime()>t1.getAllottedStartTime()){return +1;}
          if(t2.getAllottedStartTime()<t1.getAllottedStartTime()){return -1;}
          else {return 0;}
    }
    });
```

To test this I have initialised some instances of the classes and then printed the `tasksAssigned` `ArrayList`. Main method below:

```
 Dev chris=new Dev("Chris");
Dev dave=new Dev("Dave");

Task task1=new Task("LCN","",3f,1f,5f,false, new ArrayList<Dev>(Arrays.asList(chris,dave))); 
task1.setAllottedStartTime(3.5f);


Task task2=new Task("Project","",0f,3.5f,6f,false,new ArrayList<Dev>(Arrays.asList(chris)));      
task2.setAllottedStartTime(0f);

task1.setAssignedDev(chris);
task2.setAssignedDev(chris);
System.out.println(chris.getTasksAssigned());
```

Now when I run this the system prints out: `[[Task-null], [Task-null]]`
Tasks are being added but when they are returned they are null? I am expecting to see `[task1,task2]`, am I misunderstanding something?
Thanks

**Edited** to include Dev constructor as well

Comment: Can you show the code for the `getTasksAssigned()` method too?

Comment: It's just returning the arraylist: 
    `public ArrayList<Task> getTasksAssigned(){
        return tasksAssigned;        
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the only problem, but there is something seriously wrong with the `Task` constructor:

```
public Task(String newProject, String newDescription,
        float newEarliestStartTime, float newDuration,
        float newLatestFinishTime, boolean newIsTaskReferenced,
        ArrayList<Dev> newListDevs) {
    project = newProject;
    description = newDescription;
    earliestStartTime = newEarliestStartTime;
    duration = newDuration;
    latestFinishTime = newLatestFinishTime;
    isTaskReferenced = newIsTaskReferenced;
    newListDevs = new ArrayList<Dev>(); 
};
```

You pass in an `ArrayList<Dev>` to a parameter named `newListDevs`, then you assign a new, empty `ArrayList<Dev>` to the parameter just before it goes out of scope. You don't do anything with the data, if any, that was in the list that was passed to you, and the new list will be eligible for garbage collection immediately after the ctor completes.